# Tinyurl API Example - Am i doing it right :D

Tags: php, api, tinyurl

we use super-long Hashes for the Registration of new Users in our Application. The Problem is that these Hashes break in some Email Clients - making the Links unusable.

I tried implementing the Tinyurl - API, with a simple Call, but i think it times out sometimes ... sometimes the mail does not reach the user.

<strike>I updated the Code, but now the URL is never converted. Is Tinyurl really so slow or am i doing something wrong? (I mean hey, 5 Seconds is much in this Times)</strike>

Can anybody recommend me a more reliable service?

All my Fault, forgot a false in the fopen. But i will leave this sample of code here, because i often see this sample, wich i think does not work very reliable:

```
return file_get_contents('http://tinyurl.com/api-create.php?url='.$u);
```

This is the - i think fully working sample. I would like to hear about Improvements.

```
static function gettinyurl( $url ) {

    $context =
        stream_context_create(
            array(
                'http' => array(
                    'timeout' => 5  // 5 Seconds should be enough
                )
            )
        );

    // get tiny url via api-create.php
    $fp = fopen( 'http://tinyurl.com/api-create.php?url='.$url, 'r', $context); // open (read) api-create.php with long url as get parameter

    if( $fp ) { // check if open was ok
        $tinyurl = fgets( $fp ); // read response

        if( $tinyurl && !empty($tinyurl) ) // check if response is ok
            $url = $tinyurl; // set response as url

        fclose( $fp ); // close connection
    }

    // return
    return $url; // return (tiny) url
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to use [urlencode()](http://php.net/urlencode) for the `url` parameter.

It is also recommendable to check `fgets()` against `false`. Then, you could save the `empty()` function call by just comparing the response to an empty string, like:

```
$line = fgets($fp);

if ($line !== false && $line !== '') {
    // ...
}
```

Generally, it is advisable to check everything against `false` first, if the function returns values of different types such as `integer` or `boolean`. This can be crucial because `0` and `false` mean in comparisons the same. Because of PHP's lack for type safety, it is strongly recommended to always check for type equality. There are even cases when the documentation recommends this explicitly, e.g. in the case of [strpos()](http://php.net/strpos/). Meanwhile, I've forced myself to use `===` over to `==`, same for `!=' etc. It requires more typing but it is definitely worth the effort because you eliminate possible pitfalls.

The rest of your code looks good to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [bit.ly](http://bit.ly) service. It supported by google as i know.

[Api](http://code.google.com/p/bitly-api/wiki/ApiDocumentation)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly how long your hash is, but not all services (browsers, servers etc) can handle URLs longer than 255 chars. You could look into  [php's Pack()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php)

Comment: A example Hash looks like this, is always under 160 Chars.

http://testserver/confirmuser?key=c040049c01a93e8f7931e8c4b21db8f7:9d60a9aeb
3c853e3f2e099cb16bddc7c:d5c9886cb31f789ae3cdffd55456fe26

Answer (score 0):

What is the point of using a "super-long hash", if you are immediately shortening it to a 7-8 character tinyurl?

Nobody would bother with guessing the long hash, and would crack the tinyurl instead.

**Use a 10-character hash yourself and be *more* secure than you are now.**

Comment: Well ... how the Hash looks is not in my domain. I just have to send a working Email with the Hash included in it.

The Intention of the Developer was to hide some Information in the Hash, so we can reconstruct wich user wanted to register etc ...
There is also a component that is encrypted, so as long as nobody finds out the Key, our hashes are pretty secure.

And i am not sure if i understand you correctly, but why should the Tinyurl be easier or harder to crack?

Comment: Regarding tinyurl being easier to hack – if they only have a 10-character, pattern-following key, then guessing the urls (and testing to see if they redirect to your domain) will be much easier than guessing a long hash. But given that the long urls themselves are not under your control – sorry for the confusion... :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another version:

```
function getTinyUrl($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'http://' . 'tinyurl.com/api-create.php?url=' . $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $tinyUrl = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    
    if ($tinyUrl === false) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not create URL");
    }
    
    return $tinyUrl;
}
```

I had to split the tinyurl url because SO wouldn't let me post the answer.